# Welding small diameter wires together

Tags: wire, interconnect

I have a miniature two wire PT100 and need to extend its leads. Given the temperature at which it may operate, I cannot solder extensions. Is welding an option, and if so how do I go about it?

Comment: Why not crimp ?

Comment: @WesleyLee Maybe, but it is quite fine wire and will be exposed to extremes of temperature

Comment: What's the diameter of your wires?

Comment: As suggested by Wesley crimping is indeed a good option. My reflow oven uses a k type thermocouple whose leads are extended using small ferrule crimps. Thermistors in 3D printer hot ends are also crimped using ferrules.

Comment: "Crimping" *is* exactly the same as "cold welding", if it is done with a proper crimping tool.

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by extreme temperatures? Can you disclose the temperature range you are planning to use that PTC for?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Up to 600degC, but will probably not go beyond 400degC

Answer (score 8):

Sure, welding is a good option.

We use a Japanese machine that produces very repeatable welds of fine wire and exotic materials. I think it cost less than $10K USD including the head.

You could also consider brazing the leads with silver solder, which requires little equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using RTD Connectors: http://www.omega.com/pptst/OTP.html
This supports the wire and outer sheath properly.